# Выражение в текстовом формате TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Имеется строка

```
var text = '5 + 7 + 9 * (5-1*2) -1'
```

Можно ли каким то образом вычислить значение выражения в скобках?

Comment: Причём тут TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать регулярные выражения:

```js
var re = /\(.+\)/;
var text = '5 + 7 + 9 * (5-1*2) -1'

result = re.exec(text)

if (result) console.log(eval(result[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно. Для этого есть встроенная функция [`eval`](https://https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

> ***ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ***
>
> **Имейте в виду, что `eval` можно вызывать только когда вы доверяете коду. Если возможно - вообще не выполнять код, который вводит пользователь.**

Пример, как можно использовать `eval`:

```js
let text = '5 + 7 + 9 * (5-1*2) -1';
console.log(eval(text));
```

Регулярные выражения необязательны.

Comment: "вычислить значение выражения в скобках".

Comment: ааа, вот оно что.